# How do I get text from the clipboard in Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16?

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I want to read text from the clipboard in Word Visual Basic. I used to use the following code:

```
Function TextFromClipboard()
    Dim data As DataObject
    Set data = New DataObject
    data.GetFromClipboard
    TextFromClipboard = data.GetText(1)
End Function
```

but since I was forced to update Word to Version 16 this no longer works. One time I tested it, it did successfully retrieve the clipboard contents, but every other time I tried it, it returned a zero length string. I know there is text on the clipboard because I can paste it into a text file. Suggestions?

Comment: Where did you copy the data from?

Comment: Oddly, DataObject is not part of the VBA object model. THE VBA editor should be reporting it as a user-defined type. Try adding a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, then test again.

Comment: I copied the data from my bank’s Online Banking Activity page. Oddly, when I ```Paste Special``` it as ```Unformatted Text``` into a document, it pastes just fine, and then I can select it and access it via ```Selection.Range```; but this is a kludge and has its own problems and complications.

Comment: Here's the code I'm using (sorry but I can't figure out how to get code to display properly unless it's all on one line): ```Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument : Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:=wdInLine : Selection.WholeStory : TextFromClipboard = Selection.Range : On Error Resume Next : ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges```